# Socket.io and ioredis connection with SSL

Tags: sockets, ssl, socket.io, ioredis

I am trying to create a connection for sending sending messages or notifications in my application which is hosted on SSL environment. Here is what my socket file looks like:

```
var app = express();
//var server = require('https').Server();
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/my.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/my.crt'),
    requestCert: true
}

server = require('https').createServer(options, app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var Redis = require('ioredis');

var redis = new Redis();
redis.psubscribe(['*']);

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message){
//  console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel+':'+message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

And on the client side I am doing something like this :

```
var socket = io(location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname+':3000');
```

I am keep getting this error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I tried to follow some suggestions from other stackoverflow. But still not able to get it resolved.

Any suggestion will be helpful!

Thank you (in advance)!

Comment: Could you give us the full error please?

Comment: @MattFletcher the problem is now resolved by adding the keys. And installing redis on server.

Comment: Okay, glad you could solve it!